# Does anything prevent -[NSData bytes] from becoming a dangling pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a fundamental question about how Objective-C handles memory in a case like this:

```
void testimage(){
    UIImage * iu = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(iu);
    giveimage(imageData.bytes);
}
```

I have not explicitly allocated any memory, and thus I have not deleted any either. I pass the binary information onto another C function (part of a library's API) `giveimage` which then uses it for textures in a non-Objective-C codebase.

My question is: how stable is this data? It's just a pointer to some data in memory. In this context, what is preventing the system from overwriting this memory with other data? I am not holding onto it myself in any way, so are there worries here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this context, what is preventing the system from overwriting this memory with other data?

Convention: the [Cocoa rules about memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). Here, you are on the wrong side of convention. The `bytes` pointer will not last longer than its `NSData` instance. Both that `NSData` and the `UIImage` each have a lifespan limited to the `testimage` function.

In this case, you should use [`getBytes:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes:length:) to *copy* the data into your own buffer, or otherwise perform the copy. Otherwise, your fears will be realized and the data will become invalid when `testimage` returns.

Comment: Minor quibble. Once you have the `NSData` from the PNG representation, it is completely independent of the original `UIImage`. In other words, `imageData` will not be affected at all by what happens to `iu`.

Comment: Huh. I thought it was some sort of internal pointer and I needed to make an explicit copy if the `UIImage` was going to be destroyed. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have an issue. At the end of the `testimage` function, `imageData` goes out of scope and will be released. This will take its `bytes` with it.

If the data passed to `giveimage` needs to survive beyond the call to `giveimage` then your `giveimage` function needs to make its own copy of the bytes and not rely on the pointer passed to `giveimage`.